# Mysql Query returns null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In the following code, I want the username to be checked if it's available or not. The problem is that every time it gives me "Username is available" although the username that I type exists. I think the problem with the query that returns the Name. I tried to solve it but I couldn't.

```
<form method="post" action="RegConf.php">
                <p><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" onchange="check_ava()"> <span id='ava_result'></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="confPassword" name="confPassword" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" onchange="check()"> <span id='message'></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email"></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone"></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="address" value="" placeholder="Address"></p>
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="commit" value="Submit">
                <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button></p>
            </form>
```

The second part of the code:

```
function check_ava(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    <?php

mysql_connect(' ', ' ', ' ');  
mysql_select_db(' ');


$result = mysql_query("select Name from User where Name = '". "document.getElementById('username').value;" ."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
    echo "document.getElementById('ava_result').innerHTML = 'Username not available';";
    echo "document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;";
}else{  
    echo "document.getElementById('ava_result').innerHTML = 'Username is available';";
    echo "document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;";
}

?>
}
```

Comment: ohh please use ajax for mysql query. you marge up JavaScript, php and mysql

Comment: Check your query,
echo $result; exit;

Comment: so many things wrong - 1) you dont mix javascript and php like that. php runs on the server, javascript on the client. they dont talk to each other like you seem to think. 2) dont use `mysql_*`, use mysql or pdo. 3) dont concatenate parameters - use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

i'd just done this in php. Please check below code :-
i've this input box of pagename. I want to check if entered page name is exist in database or not :-

Page with this name Already Exist. Please Enter Another Page Name.

```
$("#txtPagename").blur(function(){
    var page_id = $("#page_id").val();
    var page_name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xhr/check_page.php",
        data: { page_id : page_id, page_name : page_name },
        success : function(result){
            if(result > 0){
                $("#page_exist").show();
                $("#txtPagename").val("");
            }else{
                $("#page_exist").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And in my check_page.php file i am just fetching count of pagename.

$pagename = $_POST['pagename'];
$pageid = $_POST['pageid'];
$result = mysql_query("select id from tbl_page where page_name = '$pagename' AND id != '$pageid'");
echo $usrcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
exit;

This is working example which i gave you. You can try this if its not working then put your code in fiddle or some other site so that i can have a look and rectify your problem

Answer (score 0):

You've to use Ajax Function. Try the code given below and you are done with this:-

```
function check_ava(){
var username = $('#username').val();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xhr/chk_user.php",
                data: { username : username },
                success: function(html) {
                if(html == 1){
                    $("#ava_result").html('Username not available');
                    $('#username').val('');
                }else{
                    $("#ava_result").html('Username is available');
                }



                }
            });
}
```

and in chk_user.php put this code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = mysql_query("select Name from User where Name = '$username'");
echo $usrcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
exit;
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? let me know i'll try to solve it

Comment: I tried to display the value of `username` in `var username = $('#username').val();` by using `alert` and it didn't show me anything

Comment: You are calling the function on change of username textbox so u can take $(this).val() instead of $('#username').val(). Try alerting $(this).val() and u'll get the result in alert.

Comment: Sorry nothing happened